# Get substring before and after second space in a string via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var str = "test test1 test2 test3";
```

Any way to grab "test test1" and "test2 test3"? (anything before the second space and anything after second space)

Comment: Two possible approaches: regex; splitting the string at spaces and then rebuilding the components you need.

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you know the string has at least two spaces:

```
var str = "test test1 test2 test3";

var index = str.indexOf( ' ', str.indexOf( ' ' ) + 1 );

var firstChunk = str.substr( 0, index );
var secondChunk = str.substr( index + 1 );
```

If you're unsure:

```
var str = "test test1 test2 test3";

var index = str.indexOf( ' ', str.indexOf( ' ' ) + 1 );

var firstChunk = index >= 0 ? str.substr( 0, index ) : str.substr( index + 1 );
if ( index >= 0 )
    var secondChunk = str.substr( index + 1 );
```

Comment: Hi you code works fine thanks... but if there is a leading space how to get the 1st 2 words and next 2 words? in other words how to do this for 3space? any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Using `split` and some array's functions

```js
var str = "test test1 test2 test3";

var n = 2; // second space

var a = str.split(' ')
var first = a.slice(0, n).join(' ')
var second =  a.slice(n).join(' ');

document.write(first + '<br>');
document.write(second);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexp alternative:

```
var str = "test test1 test2 test3",
    parts = str.match(/^(\S+? \S+?) ([\s\S]+?)$/);

console.log(parts.slice(1,3));   // ["test test1", "test2 test3"]
```