# Having some problems making relative reference work with an ArrayFormula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the ArrayFormula of Google Sheets to set an auto-fill system where the contents of one column update as I add more data to another column, but, with the formula I'm using, the first set of cells will just use the first value in the second set, making every cell have the same content(which is the opposite of what I want). Here's an [idea](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10lzcVnuLiEEaoyqmo2p-L7ykvZrfHXrQs0ZhrH2V7N0/edit?usp=sharing) of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Your issue is with the `=IMPORTXML` function, which can't be used with `=ARRAYFORMULA`. For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808915/google-sheets-building-dynamic-array-with-multiple-importxml-requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Google Apps Script to solve my issue, since regular formulas proved to be inefficient for what I was trying to do. Below is the code I ended up using, which populates some more fields aside from the name and icon, which still has some issues, but they're beyond the scope of this question.

```
function setHeroData(ss_id, column, row, valueInputOption) {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let range = sheet.getName() + "!" + column + row;
    sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 50);
    let domain = "https://gamepress.gg";
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${domain}/feheroes/heroes`);
    let page = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());

    const heroes = new Array(page(".icon\-cell").length+1);
    const profiles = new Array(page(".icon\-cell").length);
    const vas = new Array(page(".icon\-cell").length);
    const illus = new Array(page(".icon\-cell").length);
    let profile;
    let va;
    let ill;

    heroes[0] = [];
    heroes[0].push("Icon");
    heroes[0].push("Hero");
    heroes[0].push("Hero Epithet");
    heroes[0].push("");
    heroes[0].push("Weapon");
    heroes[0].push("")
    heroes[0].push("Movement");
    heroes[0].push("Rarity");
    heroes[0].push("Origin");
    heroes[0].push("VA (EN)");
    heroes[0].push("VA (JP)");
    heroes[0].push("Illustrator");

    page(".icon\-cell").each(function (i, elem) {
      let img = domain + page(elem).find(".hero\-icon").children("img").attr("src");
      heroes[i+1] = [];
      heroes[i+1].push(`=image("${img}", 3)`);
      heroes[i+1].push(page(elem).find(".adventurer\-title").text());

      profile = domain + page(this).children("a").attr("href");
      profiles[i] = profile;

      va = page(elem).parent().attr("data-va");
      vas[i] = va;

      ill = page(elem).parent().attr("data-ill");
      illus[i] = ill;
    });

    let prof_pages = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(profiles);

    // Get epithets from profile pages
    for (let i = 0; i<heroes.length-1; ++i) {
      let prof_page = Cheerio.load(prof_pages[i].getContentText());
      let attrib = prof_page(".vocabulary-attribute").find(".field--name-name").text();
      let attrib_img = domain + prof_page(".vocabulary-attribute").find("img").attr("src");
      let move_type = prof_page(".vocabulary-movement").find(".field--name-name").text();
      let move_type_img = domain + prof_page(".vocabulary-movement").find("img").attr("src");
      let stars = prof_page(".vocabulary-obtainable-stars").find(".field--name-name").text()[0];
      let origin = prof_page(".field--name-field-origin").text().trim();

      // Populate hero data
      heroes[i+1].push(prof_page(".field--name-title").siblings("span").text().replace(" - ", ""));
      heroes[i+1].push(`=image("${attrib_img}")`);
      heroes[i+1].push(attrib);
      heroes[i+1].push(`=image("${move_type_img}")`);
      heroes[i+1].push(move_type);
      heroes[i+1].push(`=image("https://gamepress.gg/sites/fireemblem/files/2017-06/stars${stars}.png", 3)`)
      heroes[i+1].push(origin);

      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342430/get-substring-before-and-after-second-space-in-a-string-via-javascript
      // Separate the EN and JP voice actors names
      let index = vas[i].includes(".") ? vas[i].indexOf(' ', vas[i].indexOf('.') + 2) : vas[i].indexOf(' ', vas[i].indexOf(' ') + 1);
      let en_va = index >= 0 ? vas[i].substr(0, index) : vas[i].substr(index + 1);
      let jp_va = index >= 0 ? vas[i].substr(index + 1) : "";

      if (en_va.toLowerCase() === "Cassandra Lee".toLowerCase()) {
        en_va = en_va.concat(" Morris");
        jp_va = jp_va.replace("Morris", "");
        // Logger.log(en_va);
        // Logger.log(jp_va);
      }

      heroes[i+1].push(en_va.trim());
      heroes[i+1].push(jp_va.trim());
      heroes[i+1].push(illus[i]);
      Logger.log((i*100)/(heroes.length-1));
    }

    let first_col = column.charCodeAt(0) - 64;

    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: heroes}, ss_id, range, valueInputOption);
    sheet.autoResizeColumns(first_col, heroes[0].length).autoResizeRows(row, heroes.length);
    sheet.setRowHeights(row+1, (heroes.length-1)+row, 50);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(first_col, 50);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(first_col + 3, 30);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(first_col + 5, 30);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(first_col + 7, 100);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(first_col + 8, 319);    
  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

It uses a two-dimensional array to set up the info for each row, and, using the Sheets API, populates the appropiate cells.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML is already an array-type formula (able to return arrays) therefore it is not supported under ARRAYFORMULA eg:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://gamepress.gg/feheroes/heroes", 
 "//td[@class='icon-cell'][a/div[2]='"&B2:B&"']/a/div[1]/img/@src"))
```

will not work.

try:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE("https://gamepress.gg"&
  IMPORTXML("https://gamepress.gg/feheroes/heroes", "//a/div[1]/img/@src")))
```

[image]

Comment: So making the output of `IMPORTXML` depend on what's in column B isn't possible?

Comment: @Nitram it is possible but not with B2:B array/range

Comment: What function/formula could I use then?

Comment: @Nitram did you try the 2nd formula from the answer?

Comment: Yes, but It didn't work like I wanted it to. I want to look for the icons from the website, using the names in column B (in this case) as keywords, so I get matching icons and names.

Comment: @Nitram in that case the dragging is the only option: `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),,image("https://gamepress.gg"&IMPORTXML("https://gamepress.gg/feheroes/heroes","//td[@class='icon-cell'][a/div[2]='"&B2&"']/a/div[1]/img/@src")))`

Comment: So what I'm trying to do isn't possible at the end of the day